# TypeError: .substring is not a function

Tags: javascript, acrobat

I'm running Acrobat Pro DC. I have a text field ("CC.CardNumber") with an Action/OnBlur event that runs the following script that produces this error. I've researched this for hours and can't see where my code is incorrect.

```
var fld = this.getField("CC.CardNumber");    
var first = fld.value.substring(0,1);    
fld.value = first;
```

TypeError: fld.value.substring is not a function
3:AcroForm:CC.CardNumber:Annot1:OnBlur:Action1Exception in line 1051 of function AFSimple_Calculate, script byteCodeTool

Comment: Check what `fld.value` is. It must not be a string as you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

if it is a card number then you need to convert it into a String.

var first = fld.value.toString().substring(0,1);